# click on link ask permission for app / browser using Ionic deeplinking dynamically

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Guys don't mark this question as duplicate, as i gone through many links from past 72 hours. Help me out,
I have website and app, while signup i am sending a mail from which they will verify their account. In website is working well but, while i tired to work it with app it not happening to me. In mu AndroidManifest.xml file i have written the intent:filter with all preference, plugin, .. but

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:host="xyz.com" android:path="/verifyemail/*" android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
```

here xyz is sample. My question is, 
clicking on the verify link from mail i am getting the link as follows:

```
www.xyz.com/verifymail/abc
```

here instead of abc it may be somethind else that means the various email id. How to append those and ask for the app / browser using ionic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AndroidManifest.xml, you just need to add the following:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:host="xyz.com" android:path="/verifyemail/*" android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
```

As i know we can't get dynamic link directly as the path has to be changed from abc to some other which is not possible. So, as you have to make it static and try another process to those functionality and you can able to traverse based on requirement.

Comment: Thanks @Nitin Agarwal. As per you answer i worked on it and i have change my some functionality and its working great.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a cross-platform Ionic app you might want to add this plugin: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme

You can then set a matching scheme for your app (say 'myapp') in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter>
  <data android:scheme="myapp"/>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

The URL myapp://www.xyz.com/verifymail/abc will then open your app.  Hope this helps?